# How to create an android app database that will be modified in real time?

Tags: android, database, android-database

i just started Android Development a few weeks ago for a college project : an Android application that manages the transport of students (with several buses) from their home to school with a geolocation service.
So I have already made a schema of my database. I do not want this database to be local (which is the case if I use the SQLiteOpenHelper class).
I want it to be alterable in real time :  and by that I mean: For example I am the administrator and I have a page where I can consult all the data of the students who are registered. If a new student installs the application and signs up, I need to be able to see his data directly after registration.( i hope i explained it well ) . What should I learn or look for to accomplish this task?
ANy recommendations ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Check out Firebase https://firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

If its not necessary i would recommend using a web application instead of an android application. So it works on all devices.
I have used these one for time management with some years ago

cherrypy: https://cherrypy.org/
Beside an android application you need an management website/api for your android application to communicate with, for example an rest api. cherrypy is an easy webframework to accomplish this.

jquery: https://jquery.com/
Could be used for a nice working management website using AJAX, otherwise you have to refresh the management page everytime or using frames for partially refreshing.

If you like to stay with python https://kivy.org/ is an way to create an application on android and other.

Comment: Thanky you for answering but my college project says that i should create a mobile app

Comment: *＋1* for cleaning up the other post and moving it to U&L.SE. Be careful of those [link-only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/608639) answers. You might want to add some code to avoid potential problems.